# packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed appium ERROR

Tags: android, appium

So i try to install `Facebook` on `android emulator`:

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "deviceName": "Android Emulator",
  "app": "/Users/rick/Downloads/Facebook_v240.0.0.38.121_apkpure.com.apk"
}
```

And got this error:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original
>   error: Command 'java -jar
>   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/jars/appium_apk_tools.jar
>   printLaunchActivity
>   /Users/rick/Downloads/Facebook_v240.0.0.38.121_apkpure.com.apk
>   /var/folders/pz/80vnl76n2b9850d88t18sh3c0000gn/T/com.facebook.katana'
>   exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2412) at
>   io.appium.apktools.StringsXML.silenceLogger(StringsXML.java:120) at
>   io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:25)

I also try to specify `platformVersion` (10.0) but in this case i just got another error:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Unable to find an active device or emulator with OS
>   10.0. The following are available: emulator-5554 (10)

Answer (score 0):

For your original trial. You need to specify the full path of your file not the relative path. For example C:\Users... etc.
For the second issue, you are telling the driver to connect to a machine that has android 10 on it and it's telling you that there are currently no active machines with that version installed. Make sure that you have android 10 on your device and try again.

Comment: I specified the full path snd my android emulator has version 10

Comment: @falukky Can you add the logs after adding the full path?